# Retrieving dump file from Galaxy watch widget crash

Tags: dump, tizen, galaxy

I am building a Galaxy (Tizen) watch app and widget.  My widget crashes with this error:

```
crash-manager.c: scan_dump(885) > [5] path: /opt/usr/share/crash/dump//myapp.widget_29200_20210228083344.zip(FILE), size: 1072 kb, mtime: Sun Feb 28 08:33:57 2021
```

So I went to the Tizen device manager, connect to the running watch emulator, and browse the file system on the watch.  While there is a /opt/usr/share/crash directory, there is nothing in that directory (not even a 'dump' subdirectory).

Why is this file missing?  How can I tell the watch to save the file / how can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with elevation.  The file explorer in Tizen Device Manager runs with regular user permissions; so many files/folders are not visible.

You need to open an SDB shell, then elevate with 'su' command.  (Password is "tizen").  Then copy the debug files to /tmp from the command line and the file explorer can then extract/pull the files to your local PC for examination.

I believe this is poor design on Tizen's part, but at least there is a workaround.

Comment: I'm after the same solution, but for `su` I got `sh: su: command not found`. By any chance have you got any idea?